# No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created

Tags: java, database, eclipse, maven, liquibase

The problem consist in:
When play the command maven, the seems problem find in https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-465, but is that 2009, can marked with "Cannot Reproduce", i'm use one file .xml type liquibase with one changeSet, but many createTable, addPrimaryKey, rollback, addForeignKeyConstraint, this file create always tables and your respective constraints, but i'm make a rollback this wrong happened,  i'm tired find for Internet, then can't found solution for the problem, are you can solved this problem? share with the community!

The plugin and command use for a maven at this:

```
liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=payScript -PproductionPostgreSql
```

the plugin at this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/changelogs/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <driver>${driver}</driver>
        <url> ${host.db}</url>
        <username>${user.db}</username>
        <password>${password.db}</password>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

this produced the stack trace below

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:rollback (default-cli) on project generic: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:rollback (default-cli) on project generic: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created
>       at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:398)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>       ... 20 more
>   Caused by: liquibase.exception.RollbackFailedException: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created
>       at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.rollback(ChangeSet.java:648)
>       at liquibase.changelog.visitor.RollbackVisitor.visit(RollbackVisitor.java:39)
>       at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
>       at liquibase.Liquibase.rollback(Liquibase.java:656)
>       at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseRollback.performLiquibaseTask(LiquibaseRollback.java:121)
>       at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
>       ... 22 more
>   Caused by: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created
>       at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.generateRollbackStatementsFromInverse(AbstractChange.java:424)
>       at liquibase.change.AbstractChange.generateRollbackStatements(AbstractChange.java:397)
>       at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeRollbackStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1269)
>       at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.rollback(ChangeSet.java:634)
>       ... 27 more
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Somewhere in your changelog, you have a changeset that uses raw SQL. You didn't include it here, but the actual contents don't matter - as long as it is raw SQL, Liquibase cannot determine how to 'undo' or rollback that change. The way to fix this is to look at that changeset and add a rollback tag to that changeset that describes how to rollback the change made.

The docs here http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html are for the SQL tag. Rollback in general is described here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html

In particular, note this paragraph:

> Other refactorings such as “drop table” and “insert data” have no
>   corresponding rollback commands that can be automatically generated.
>   In these cases, and cases where you want to override the default
>   generated rollback commands, you can specify the rollback commands via
>   the tag within the changeSet tag. If you do not want anything done to
>   undo a change in rollback mode, use an empty tag.

Here is an example that shows a raw SQL changeset and a corresponding rollback tag.

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">
    <sql dbms="h2, oracle"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="true">insert into person (name) values ('Bob')
        <comment>What about Bob?</comment>
    </sql>
    <rollback>
        delete from person where name='Bob';
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Note that this is a **VERY** naive example - you probably wouldn't want to use this in a real scenario, because it is possible that after you had run `liquibase update` to deploy this change that whatever programs using the database might insert rows into the person table with the name 'Bob', and this rollback statement would remove ALL the rows with name 'Bob'.

Comment: this "In particular, note this paragraph:" I'm one chageSet with SQL update, it's not has a tag rollback, **but no the changeSet has contemn a  tag  payScript**, but the tag was placed rollback and worked

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. It sounds like things are working for you.

Comment: While helpful, this answer contains a contradiction in that it states "Somewhere in your changelog, you have a changeset that uses raw SQL", but then lists liquibase change types that "have no corresponding rollback commands that can be automatically generated". It would be more accurate and less confusing to state something like "Somewhere in your changelog, you have a changeset that *either* uses raw SQL *or* a liquibase change type that liquibase can not automatically roll back as per the list [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/liquibase-auto-rollback.html)".

Comment: Comment above from Woodchuck is correct. There are multiple things that you can put in a changelog that do not have an automatic inverse. The error message in the original question said "No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created" but the messages for things that can't automatically be 'inverted' will all have a message somewhat like that.